# Black screen with blinking underscore after new Ubuntu 22.04 instaltion

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, screen

I recently acquired a new ssd drive and decided to install a fresh Ubuntu installation on it. Upon booting the system, now that Ubuntu 22.04.1 is now installed, I am met with the motherboard flash screen. After four beeps, separated by 15-20 seconds, **a blank screen is displayed and on it in the top left corner is a blinking white underscore.** I can’t type in this view nor will any ctl alt f’s work to display anything beyond the previously mentioned screen. Holding/tapping shift on start up also does nothing. **However the above only occurs when my dedicated Gpu is installed. While used my computers integrated graphics the system boots fine.** Is there any way to fix this issue and what would be the cause/fix?

System specifications as follows
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-B75M-D3H
CPU: Intel i5 3470
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 ti
SSD: 250gb SanDisk 3D Ultra
Ubuntu: 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: 5.15.0-53-generic

If any other specifics are needed just ask and I will update as necessary.

I have tried installing latest NVIDIA drivers compatible with Gpu with no results (*Note did not work before or after drivers installed*). In addition to updating kernel from 5.15.0.52 to current 6.0.6, to no avail. I will apologize in advance for my limited knowledge of Linux and how to work around the system. More thorough directions may be needed depending on the intended solution. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I was able to get a friend to try this graphics card on his computer. He has a windows based PC wheres mine is Linux, and I figured before I tossed it that it was worth giving it a try. Much to my surprise he said that it booted just fine using my GPU.

Is there any information that anyone can give for why my Gpu isn’t running on my Computer? Is this a Problem with Linux 22.04? Is this something that can be fixed and if so am I better off getting a hold of Linux/Ubuntu instead?
If anyone else has had/is experiencing this issue let me know as I would be interested to see if this is a compatibility issue across all Ubuntu/Linux or just on my PC.

Comment: Before you changed the hard drive did it make the 4 beeps on start up?

Comment: Yes, this is something that the computer does on every startup while the mopboard flash screen is displayed,(including with the old hard drive that was installed). It does however, only beep once just briefly while  flashing the motherboard (Gigabytes) screen before it continues to boot. I had thought that this was a result of the new ssd, but am still confused as to why it would be the same time and process as with the old drive when I try to boot with my dedicated Gpu.

Comment: Why did you install 20.04.1? Latest version (to which you have to upgrade to) is [ubuntu-20.04.5](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso)

Comment: I didn’t realize, until after installing, that I could update. My previous install was not updated past 20.04.1 and when I reinstalled I just put the same thing that was on it previously. As of today I have updated to 22.04.1, after being prompted by software installer. Hoping my problem would be resolved, update has not changed anything. But hey I have the latest Ubuntu now as a bonus. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @david , to specify about the startup. The computers four beeps occurred before I changed the hard drive(at this point I was using the same GPU), and  when it beeps once is when I am using integrated graphics. My previous response did not specify when I got the single beep.

Comment: I have updated this Response based on further information gotten, and am still looking for help/input if there is anyone out there with any ideas or experience with this.